# Identify Connector on Clearpath Husky

Tags: connector, identification, cables

can you please help me identify this connector?

It is used on the **Clearpath Husky** to connect the battery to the robot.
The top image shows the male (from the charger) and the bottom one the connector female part attached to the battery. Both have a tiny letter *A* printed on the mating side. They seem to be modular and single modules can be slided on or off.

I want to buy some spares and make my own cable.
Thanks!

[image: Male]

[image: Female]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got an answer from the Clearpath support team.
Turns out the plugs are **Anderson Powerpole Connectors**.
They use the 261G2 contacts and the PP15-45 housings. See the [datasheet here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/22/ds-pp1545-766098.pdf).

I believe they are very similar if not identical to the AMP Power Series as mentioned by dim.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like TE connectivity "AMP Power Series" connectors. There are several versions (15/30/45/50/75/120/whatever). Here is the [datasheet](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Catalog+Section%7F1773096_SEC02_CABLE_MOUNTED%7F0210%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CS_1773096_SEC02_CABLE_MOUNTED_0210.pdf%7F1604398-4). Look starting from page 141, take a caliper, and check which one is yours.

**Edit**: I'm pretty sure it is actually the AMP Power Series 15/30/45. The housing is the same for these three versions, the difference being the contact and its current carrying capability. It may be more difficult to guess which one of these variants it is. Maybe you can just try the one that has the highest capability, and check that it mates appropriately.

Comment: Yep, seems like its that one. Thanks! I will buy a couple of them and tell you what worked.